# EF object property changing - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a viewmodel that has an EF object as one of its properties. The view has several text boxes wired up to that property via `Text="{Binding Path=MyEFTable.Column1}"`.  I'm using the MVVM Light toolkit so my viewmodels inherit ViewModelBase and subsequently each property calls `RaisePropertyChanged()` when changed.

I have noticed, however that changing `MyEFTable.Column1` does not set off any changes in the viewmodel.  I thought that EF objects tracked any changes, so I assumed that changing a column value in an EF object would cause the EF object itself to be changed. Is it no longer tracking changes since I am essentially copying the query result into a new `MyEFTable` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your bindable objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged or it's container, like ObservableCollection?
Are you rising the event?

Using a view model is only the start. First thing you should check is to see if the Column1 Property is being updated after the editing occurs. If a TextBox, the UpdateSourceTrigger default value is LostFocus. Maybe you can try change it to PropertyChanged.
If the value is updated in your MyEFTable.Column1 you're done. If not, again, something is using the INotifyPropertyChange.

Add more info and maybe the issue will be clearer.

HTH

Comment: If the bindable object is an EF entity, doesn't it already implement INotifyPropertyChanged? I did some testing and found that the object's properties are changing, so all I really need to do now is figure out a way to save them back to the database.  I was hoping to avoid view event triggers, but I guess that may be the easiest way.

Comment: I don't they implement INPC, but if the properties in your bindable object you have most of your problem solved :)